# Как изменить код

Tags: php, javascript

В данном коде кнопка появляется при нажатии в каком нибудь месте блока. А как сделать так, чтобы только при нажатии ссылки в этом блоке появилась кнопка?

```html
<div class="column_3" id="hidden_link1" onclick="document.all.hidden_link2.style.display='block';" style="display:none">
<a align="center" class="vklady_1" href="javascript:document.getElementById('plan').value=1;with(document.getElementById('vklad_form')){ submit(); }">
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Получить бонус"></a>
```

Comment: Пример на jq `$('a').on('click', function(){$('#block').append('<input type=submit>');return 0;});`